# TypeScript compiles seemingly invalid variable type declaration

Tags: typescript

I was declaring a class variable in TypeScript application (`typescript:3.2.4`, `tslint:5.14.0`) like so:

```
export class Foo {

  private bar: 137;
  
  ...
  
}
```

This was a typo, I *meant* `private bar = 137`.

My question is why did this compile, and why didn't TSLint give any warnings?

At runtime, both the value and `typeof` were `undefined`. How was this being interpreted by the TypeScript compiler; what did it think I wanted? Is there any functional situation where the type of a variable could be a primitive value like `137`?

## Additional Cases:

Similarly, the following *does* compile:

```
export class Foo {

  private bar: 'bar';
  
  ...
  
}
```

The following *does not* compile:

```
export class Foo {

  private bar: 137 = 42;
  
  ...
  
}
```

The compiler error is `error TS2322: Type '42' is not assignable to type '137'.`

What's going on here?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types

Comment: I agree that this is confusing and can lead to typos, which typescript is supposed to prevent. I’d prefer a warning like: “did you mean to assign a literal value as a type? “...

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe linked to, this is a valid expression in TypeScript called [literal typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types).

To answer my question for anyone who might have be asking the same..

```
export class Foo {

  private bar: 137;

}
```

is interpreted by the compiler to say that `bar` is `undefined` and can only be assigned the value `137`.

A more practical case would be to permit a couple of options, e.g.:

```
export class Foo {

  private bar: 0 | 25 | 50 | 75 | 100;

  constructor() {
    this.bar = 25;
    this.bar = 100;
    this.bar = 137; // compile time error
  }

}
```

The operation `this.bar = 137` throws the compile time error:

`error TS2322: Type '137' is not assignable to type '0 | 100 | 50 | 25 | 75'`